# Making a 3d array MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

In MATLAB I have

```
[Z,S]=meshgrid(0.01:0.01:1)
```

and I also have a 100000x2 matrix called X, each row has two sets of data - p is the first column and x is the 2nd.

I want to compute exp^(-S*X(j,2)).(*Z.^X(j,1)) where j indexes the row. The result should be a 100x100x100000 matrix. This will then be averaged along the 3rd dimension and a mesh plot will be produced. I've tried using a for loop

```
[Z,S]=meshgrid(0.01:0.01:1)
for j=1:100000
phi(j)=exp^(-S.*X(j,2)).*(Z.^X(j,1))
end
```

to produce the 100x100x100000 array I need. However this gives me the error

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
Error in phi (line 4)
phi(j)=exp(-S.*X(j,2)).*(Z.^X(j,1));
```

I'm not sure why this is happening? Can anyone figure out a better way of trying to find the result I want? Because I'm guessing there could be a fully vectorised solution (or least use of for loops)?

Comment: I'm having trouble following your indices - can you say a little bit more about the object you're trying to create?  Is this like an 2D exponential with random noise or something?

Comment: You are trying to assign a matrix to a single spot in `phi`.  You are obviously getting a dimension mismatch because of that.

Comment: @anon0909 no that part isn't a 2D exponential - I'm trying to calculate e^(-sp)z^x, where the p and x are random variables stored in the array X. 100000 samples have been taken so that each row of X has a p and x corresponding to one sample. The j in my question simply numbers which particular sample we are looking at. I will then want to average over all the samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you are using two more nested loops to get `Z` and `S`, thus the code would have three nested loops in total.

Now, the vectorizing techniques haven't changed on vectorizable nested loops cases like these - *Treat different parts of the code that involve different iterators separately*. Thus, here you have three iterators, two of which are `100` in length and the third ones goes until `100000`. Putting the vectorizing ideas in a concise commented text and solving your case with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based code -

```
%// Get vectorized equivalent of exp(-S.*X(j,2)) and keeping in mind that
%// since the last (3rd) dimension of final output has length same as the 
%// number of elements in X(:,2), so "throw" this to 3rd dim with permute. 
%// Then, use bsxfun to let the broadcasting being taken care off by MATLAB.
p1 = exp(-bsxfun(@times,V.',permute(X(:,2),[3 2 1]))); %//'

%// Going with same philosophy as before, get vectorized (Z.^X(j,1))
p2 = bsxfun(@power,V,permute(X(:,1),[3 2 1]));

%// Finally "merge" earlier two parts for final output
phi_out = bsxfun(@times,p1,p2);
```

Comment: This worked for me quite well. Whilst the actual function unfortunately produced large values so as a result of using this I was able to successfully eliminate producing the plot I wanted (phi_out) in my project. Your answer does however have some really useful tips so I appreciate the help greatly.